# Making a $\pi$-periodic function into a $2\pi$-periodic one

Tags: functions

Given the function
$$f(x)=\sin(x)$$
for $x\in[0,\pi]$, I have to find its even expansion for all real number such that its period is $2\pi$.

What I thought was to take
$$g(x)=|\sin(x)|$$
which would give me what I want, but the period of $g$ is clearly $\pi$, not $2\pi$ as the exercise asks for.

Comment: $g(x) = f(x/2)$ ?

Comment: @Nephanth $f(x/2)$ is not an even function.

Comment: A $\pi$-periodic function is also $2\pi$-periodic.  The requirement that $g$ be even determines $g$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, so you have the correct answer.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I know. But it seems it asks for to be a $2\pi$-periodic like $\sin(x)$, for example.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that the smallest period be $2\pi$.